# How to make an element two sides bounded and two sides open in react-draggable?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Currently, the element cannot move outside the container with class of card-width-height. I want the two sides right and botton bounded whereas top and right should be open i.e. the element can move beyond the container but must be hidden. Can anyone help me out.

```
import React from "react";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";
import "../css/touch.css";

class Card extends React.Component {

  handleStart = (e, data) => {
    console.log(e, data);
  };

  handleStop = (e, data) => {
    console.log(e, data);
  };

  render() {
     return (  
      <div className="card-width-height">
        <Draggable
          axis="both"
          bounds="parent"
          defaultPosition={{ x: 180, y: 200 }}
          handle=".handle"
          onStart={this.handleStart}
          onStop={this.handleStop}
        >
          <div className="handle child-card" style={{ width: "50%" }}>
            <div>Screen 1</div>
          </div>
        </Draggable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Card;
```

Here is the css code

```
.card-width-height {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 360px;
  min-height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child-card {
  height: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify movement boundaries by `bounds`

> An object with `left, top, right, and bottom` properties.
>   These indicate how far in each direction the draggable can be moved.
>
> bounds: {left: number, top: number, right: number, bottom: number}

so you need to change like this
`bounds= {{left: 0, top: -100, right:360, bottom:350}}`.all the numbers depend on your width and height parameters.

check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-http-visrj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) out in practice and see for yourself.